# Overriding functionality of special keys on CM Storm Trigger keyboard

Tags: keyboard, key-mapping, i3

I have a CM Storm Trigger Keyboard. This has some special keys, which can be programmed to trigger certain macros. There are special "M" keys for macros on the left-hand side, and there are two "Trigger" keys instead of the Super Key. When I click this key plus a numbered key, the whole keyboard lights up (it's a gaming keyboard).

However, I am not a gamer and do not care much about the lights. Rather, I want to use the "super key" functionality in its original format. Most importantly, I want to assign this as the "Mod1" modifier key in the i3 window manager. But currently, this is impossible to do. The key is not assigned any function, it appears. I used 'xev' and when I press this particular key, absolutely nothing happens. It shows no event, so I can not check out the name of the key. Xmodmap is not very useful either, I can not identify this key this way.

Any idea how to 'activate' / identify this key?

Comment: Does it register anything using `showkey` from the console? You can also check for a scancode, see [the Arch Wiki multimedia keys page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multimedia_Keys#Using_showkey).

Comment: Thanks. It does not appear using `showkey`, nor does it appear in `dmesg`, so I guess I am out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I have a mechanical gaming keyboard and a whole set of the keys don't show up in Linux. C'est la vie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `xev` doesn't register a response for a particular keypress, then you can try at the next level down with `showkey`, a command that must be issued from the console.

If `showkey` provides not information about a keypress, your final option is to see if it is registering with the kernel; follow the instructions on the [Arch Linux Wiki multimedia keys page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multimedia_Keys#Using_showkey), and check for a scancode by seeing what is printed (if anything) to `dmesg` after a keypress.

If none of the above approaches return a result for the key, then it is not accessible in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can use M keys on the CM trigger on linux by writing a macro on them with the windows trigger's software, as they are saved on the trigger's board, on the right keyboard profile the macro will work even on linux. (working for me with debian)

Answer (score 0):

The left "Trigger" key can be assigned as the "Windows Key" from within Windows using the Trigger's custom configuration software. Once this has been done the key will be accessible from within *nix; since it will now send a signal out of the keyboard which it previously wasn't doing. (This works for me, using Gentoo.)

Instructions and software available here: http://www.cmstorm.com/en/products/keyboards/Trigger/

Support tab, second question "How to setup Windows key to the Storm logo key?".

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Trigger apps and assign the storm key as windows key.
After all, you need so call to execute the Profile or what we said to activate the profile by pressing Right Storm Key with number 1 to 5, either one number depends which profile you assign the function key.

Comment: The message you're trying to convey here seems unclear. Could you rephrase for more clarity?